# JQuery on event not working for dynamic listitem

Tags: jquery

I have tried the following code, in which I am having problem with `<li>`, 
that is dynamically inserted by jquery, Click event on `<li>` is not firing at all.

Should i use `.on()` or `.delegate()`?

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type=text/javascript     src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul li").on("click",function(){
    alert("hi");

});
$(":button").click(function(){
    var ul=$("ul");
    var txt=$(":text").val();
    ul.append("<li>" + txt + "<button>X</button></li>");
});


}); 

</script>
<style>
button
{
border:none;
float:right;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:white;
cursor:pointer;
font-size:30px
}
body
{
background-color:#AB19CD;

}
div
{
margin:100px auto;
width:520px;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
line-height:100px
}
input[type=text]
{
width:400px;
height:100px;
border:none;
font:300 30px/100px 'Verdana';
box-sizing:box-border;
outline:none;
padding-left:10px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
float:left
}
input[type=button]
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:none;
font:300 30px/100px 'Verdana';
float:left
}
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0
}
li
{
float:left;
width:500px;
height:100px;
background-color:white;
text-align:left;
padding-left:10px;
font:300 30px/100px 'Verdana';
margin-top:10px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type=text placeholder=Password><input type=button value=Add>
<ul></ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Change

```
$("ul li").on("click",function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

to

```
$("ul").on("click", "li" ,function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

This way you're static `ul` will delegate the click event to the `li`.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer, so the author is properly rewarded.

Comment: Since he brought it up in the question, just a note on `delegate` - this was introduced to jQuery during a transition period between the much older `live` method and the new syntax shown here with the use of `on`. While `delegate` would work correctly, it should be considered deprecated (not sure if it has been officially marked as such). The `on` syntax is the newest, preferred syntax for accomplishing this.

Comment: @Nate the reason `on` is used more is because it uses the `bind` syntax. `delegate`'s syntax might be confusing for some ppl.. first u add the element, then the event handler..thats kinda weird.. thats why it never caught on when compared to `bind`. there are no performance differences between `on` and `delegate`.

Comment: @hungerpain, your answer worked fine, But another problem arise, is that, When i click on listitem, alert is displayed, but after that, Add button is not working and I am unable to add new listitem, why is it so?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this at jsfiddle.net?